# vs code: I am running a script in the terminal, how can I cmd+click to open files from its output when the relative path is difference

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am running a script in the integrated terminal, this outputs some file paths with a different relative path (additional ../../).
Now when I cmd+click the path, it tries to open the file `../../path/here/file.txt` but it doesnt find it because `../../` are not needed.

any idea how can I (from within vscode) fix this? to have the editor ignore the `../../` or just search with the file name?

I have thought of modifying the script to ignore the ../../, but I dont want to.

Edit:
I managed to edit the relative path parent in the tasks.json that runs the script, and not it works.

```
"/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
    "problemMatcher": {
      "base": "$gcc",
      "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceRoot}/relative/path"]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Python extension setting, chek the following: "Execute in File Dir". It works for me. The default is unchecked (home directory is used by default). You may need to set `"terminal.integrated.cwd": "${fileDirname}"` in the setting.json also.

[image]